# How to substitute the nth occurrence pattern in VI editor

Tags: text-processing, vi

The contents of the file

```
This is a demo file
*******************
This is the 1st line the the the.
This is the 2nd line the the.
This is the third line the the.
This is the 5th line.
This is the 6th line.
This is the 7th line.
This is the 8th line.
This is the 9th line.
This is the 10th line.
```

In the 3rd line there are 4 instances of `the`.

I want to change only the 3rd occurrence of `the` to `THE`.

in ex mode if I type

```
:s/the/THE/g
```

it will change all `the` to `THE`, so how to change the 3rd "the" to "THE"?

Comment: in the third line there are 3 instances of `the`, as far as I can see. And why don't you paste your file into the question rather than posting an image of it? It would be easier to deal with that way. What about the other lines? Don't you want to operate on those at all?

Comment: @Zanna I think OP means the truly third line, not the one marked as third (which is actually the fifth).

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto fair point :)

Comment: By the way OMG I just realized I ended up on a vi question... O.o How am I going to exit now? :P

Comment: Do you want instructions for capitalizing the third occurrence of `the` on every line of any file? Just a single line of any file? Just this particular line of this particular file? Do the `the`s have to be separate words? Can you **[edit]** this to explain more about what you want? If you want something that performs an operation on any file, rather than being specific to the buffer you have shown, can you give some other examples besides that one? Also, as @Zanna says, [please post text as text unless you have something only an image can show](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/22949).

Comment: I fixed the pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace each N<sup>th</sup> occurrence of PATTERN in a line with REPLACE.

```
:%s/\(.\{-}\zsPATTERN\)\{N}/REPLACE/
```

Replace N<sup>th</sup> occurrence of PATTERN in 3<sup>rd</sup> line only with REPLACE.

```
:3s/\(.\{-}\zsPATTERN\)\{N}/REPLACE/
```

In your givin sample, just use the command as following.

```
:3s/\(.\{-}\zsthe\)\{3}/THE/
```

Comment: can anyone explain how \zs and \ze works

Comment: please see `:help zs` and `:help ze` in Vi

Comment: also see a good answer [here on vi.stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3039/7940)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could select the third line using `3` then use interactive mode (`gc`)

```
:3s/the/THE/gc
```

You get

```
replace with THE (y/n/a/q/l/^E/^Y)?
```

press <kbd>n</kbd> (no) <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd> (yes) <kbd>q</kbd> (quit)

Comment: Yes this one works. But is there any more ways to do that.

Comment: I think here the flag /g means for the all occurrences. So is there a way to select and substitute only the 3rd occurrence.

Comment: [I don't think there is a simple way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073865/substitute-the-n-th-occurrence-of-a-word-in-vim) @user5499810 but if the lines are very long searching twice as suggested there might be easier than using interactive mode